# Where clause not working in my mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have implemented a Mysql query with many where conditions but it is not giving right result.I have to find data where user_id is not equal to 7 but it is giving me result with user_id 7.here is both queries i run but not giving me right result.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tr_truck` 
WHERE (`user_id` != 7 AND `body_type_id` = 1 ) 
        AND ( `truck_capacity_id` = 1 AND `truck_wheel_id` = 2 ) 
        OR ( `truck_wheel_id` = 2 AND `truck_length_id` = 1 ) 
        OR (`truck_capacity_id` = 1 AND `truck_length_id` = 1 )
```

and another query i run is

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tr_truck` 
WHERE ( `truck_capacity_id` = 1 AND `truck_wheel_id` = 2 ) 
        OR ( `truck_wheel_id` = 2 AND `truck_length_id` = 1 ) 
        OR (`truck_capacity_id` = 1 AND `truck_length_id` = 1 ) 
        AND `user_id` NOT IN (7) AND `body_type_id` = 1
```

I also tried to replave <> operator with != but to no avail.Here is screenshot of my database result.
https://prnt.sc/kskl08

Comment: Please add sample data and the expected result

Comment: Mixing ands and ors like that could well result in 'incorrect' results. Use bracketing to enforce the conditions you want. You can improve the question by adding sample data and expected output as text to the question.

Comment: i don't understand why this is downvoted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try this, I rearrange the brackets arragement

query 1

```
SELECT * 
    FROM `tr_truck` 
    WHERE (`user_id` != 7 AND `body_type_id` = 1 AND `truck_capacity_id` = 1 AND `truck_wheel_id` = 2 ) 
    AND
     ( (`truck_wheel_id` = 2 AND `truck_length_id` = 1 ) 
   OR ( `truck_capacity_id` = 1 AND `truck_length_id` = 1 ))
```

query 2

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tr_truck` 
WHERE (( `truck_capacity_id` = 1 AND `truck_wheel_id` = 2 ) 
        OR ( `truck_wheel_id` = 2 AND `truck_length_id` = 1 ) 
        OR (`truck_capacity_id` = 1 AND `truck_length_id` = 1 ) )
        AND (`user_id` NOT IN (7) AND `body_type_id` = 1 )
```